# UISearchbar Static Tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, static, uisearchbar

Is it possible to have a `UISearchBar` on Static Cells, I really need the static cells, and there are like 40 of them, so how can I use the `UISearchBar` in it?
My Cells are filled with a button (Every name has another button (Every Cell has another name)).

**So basically I need to search for the button text onto of each cell, and for that show the cells that contain the search string.**

Can someone provide help please?
Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Why do you 'need' static cells?

Comment: Because I am using a tableviewcontroller with buttons on the cells, when the button is clicked, a variable per button is send to the next view controller that is also pushed by that button.

Comment: Nothing in that requires static cells. Static cells are a convenience if they help you. Otherwise they are a hindrance where a prototype cell and a configuration array may be a much better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use static cells, as you probably already know, you don't implement the delegate methods in your UITableViewController. However, if you want to only display some of your static cells (or change the ones displayed), you can implement the delegate methods and call super on them after making whatever changes you need.

So by this I mean... If I have a static table view with 1 section, 3 cells, and I only want to display the first cell and the last cell, I would implement `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`, and have it return 2. Then I would implement `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, and when it gets called with the index path with section 0, row 0, I'll call the superclass method with section 0 row 0. And when it gets called with section 0 row 1, I'll call the superclass with section 0 row 2. Basically, I'm mapping from indices of rows that will be displayed to the indices in the complete static table as defined in the storyboard.

However, I would suggest that you don't need to use static cells at all, and it will be a lot simpler. You won't have to deal with this mapping to make this work. You would maybe want to use static cells if your cells have `UITextField`s in them, or some other type of view that could cause problems for reuse. But in your case, a dynamic table would be much better to use because you don't have any content in a cell that would need to possibly be saved if a cell were going to be reused at a different index.

If you go the dynamic table route, you just need to implement the delegate for the search bar, and as you type you will store the list of filtered results in an array stored in an instance variable or property, and reload your table, using that array as the data source.